# xp_cmdshell could not find server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have enabled the `XP_CMDSHELL` and tried to execute the following line of code:

```
EXEC Master..XP_CMDSHELL 'bcp "exec server.db.dbo.SProc" queryout c:\test\test.txt -k -t \t -c -S localhost -T';
```

but I got the following error:

> SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 7202
>   Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native
>   Client 10.0][SQL Server] Could not find
>   server in sysservers. Execute
>   sp_addlinkedserver to add the server
>   to sysservers.

But when I execute the stored procedure outside `XP_CMDSHELL` it works fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind `xp_cmdshell` executes in the context of the SQL Server machine you call it from.

It sounds like the server is not listed on the actual server machine running your SQL Server.  If it is on the same server you are calling it from, try using `localhost` or the internal IP address.